# cellular approximation theorem references

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Can someone give some references to a proof of cellular approximation theorem that you consider "easy enough" to understand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a proof in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* (theorem 4.8, page 349 in the current version).

Whether or not it's "easy enough to understand" is harder to judge, but I don't think you can find something much easier (although I'd be glad to be corrected)